# C# Ms Sql добавление в модель базы данных две таблицы

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, sql-server, visual-studio

Есть модель таблицы

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
namespace Asp.Models
{
    public class Model
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Key]
        public long ID { get; set; } // Id юзеров и чатов
        public int MessageId { get; set; }
        public bool Chat { get; set; } // true - id => Id чата, false - id => Id юзера
        public string UserToken { get; set; } = default!; // Токен юзера
        public string ChatName { get; set; } = default!; // Название чата

    }
}
```

По Id могу обращаться к данным таблицы, но хочу в таблице хранить что то вроде массива

```
public string[] Message { get; set; }
```

Чтобы по id пользователя был доступ к сообщениям которые хранятся в базе данных.
В интернете примеров не нашел, что именно нужно искать для этой реализации

Comment: [Отношение один ко многим](https://metanit.com/sharp/efcore/3.5.php) ?

Comment: спасибо огромное, вроде то что нужно